# Why does the method "onLayout" of a custom view keep being called when used in a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a custom view which overrides a method onLayout, and it is in one of my Fragment. I found when this view is created, the onLayout method just keeps being called. I think it's not my view's problem because I have tried several different custom views which extend ImageView or SurfaceView, all have the same problem. When I put my view in an Activity, the method onLayout is just called twice and I know it's ok. Anyone know why and how to fix it?

P.S. my Fragment is added using class FragmentTransaction in my code, is that the reason?

Comment: show the documentation where it states it should not be called?

Comment: this method is "Called from layout when this view should assign a size and position to each of its children" based on Google API. But I don't know why it keeps being called when this view is in a Fragment. Could it be that the view is assigning a size or position all the time?

Comment: what you mean "all the time"? if you want to know why its called add Thread.dumpStack() in onLayout